# Python multithreaded server can handle one client message at a time

Tags: python, multithreading

I was playing around to understand multithreading so I wrote the following client/server application, where the server sends a command to the client, the client checks this command if it is equal to 'a' it sends a reply to the server.

In the server code I created two sockets and one thread; the first socket sends (publishes) the command to all of the connected (subscribed) clients. In the thread the second socket waits for any reply from the clients but because the thread performs some blocking operations (e.g. storing the information sent by the client in a database) it can handle one client at a time even though the socket (req-rep socket) can receive multiple message at the same time.

**server.py**

```
import zmq
import logging
import threading
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


class Server(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.pub_port = 7777
        self.rep_port = 7778

        self.pub_socket = None
        self.rep_socket = None
        self.interface = "*"

    def bind_ports(self):
        logging.debug("[bind_ports] binding the ports....")
        self.pub_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.PUB)
        pub_bind_str = "tcp://{}:{}".format(self.interface, self.pub_port)
        self.pub_socket.bind(pub_bind_str)

        self.rep_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.REP)
        rep_bind_str = "tcp://{}:{}".format(self.interface, self.rep_port)
        self.rep_socket.bind(rep_bind_str)

    def received_info(self):
        while True:
            # logging.debug("[received_flow] ")
            cl_data = self.rep_socket.recv_json()
            logging.info("[received_data] data <{}>".format(flow))
            self.rep_socket.send(b"\x00")
            self.blocking_op(cl_data)

    def blocking_op(self, data):
        time.sleep(1) # simulating some blocking operations e.g. storing info in a database

    def push_instruction(self, cmd):
        logging.debug("[push_inst] Sending the instruction <%s> to the clients...",
        # logging.debug("[push_inst] Sending the instruction <%s> to the agents ...",
         cmd)
        instruction = {"cmd": cmd}
        self.pub_socket.send_json(instruction)

    def create_thread(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.received_info)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
        logging.debug("[create_thread] Thread created <{}>".format(
                                                        thread.is_alive()))

    def start_main_loop(self):
        logging.debug("[start_main_loop] Loop started....")
        self.bind_ports()
        self.create_thread()

        while True:
            cmd = input("Enter your command: ")
            self.push_instruction(cmd)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Server().start_main_loop()
```

**client.py**

```
import zmq
import logging
import random
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class Client(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.sub_socket = None
        self.req_socket = None

        self.pub_port = 7777
        self.req_port = 7778
        self.server_ip = 'localhost'

        self.client_id = ""

    def connect_to_server(self):
        logging.debug("[conn_to_serv] Connecting to the server ....")
        self.sub_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        self.sub_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
        conn_str = "tcp://{}:{}".format(self.server_ip, self.pub_port)
        self.sub_socket.connect(conn_str)

        self.req_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.REQ)
        req_conn_str = "tcp://{}:{}".format(self.server_ip, self.req_port)
        self.req_socket.connect(req_conn_str)

    def get_instruction(self):
        inst = self.sub_socket.recv_json()
        logging.debug("[get_inst] Server sent inst")
        cmd = inst["cmd"]
        return cmd
    def send_flow(self, x, y):
        flow = {
            "client_id": self.client_id,
            "x": x,
            "y": y
        }
        self.req_socket.send_json(flow)

    def start_main_loop(self):
        logging.debug("starting the main loop ....")
        self.client_id = input("What is your id: ")
        self.connect_to_server()

        while True:
            inst = self.get_instruction()
            logging.info("[Main_loop] inst<{}>".format(inst))
            if inst == "a":
                # time.sleep(random.uniform(.6, 1.5))
                self.send_flow("xxx", "yyy")
                self.req_socket.recv()
                logging.debug("[main_loop] server received the flow")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Client().start_main_loop()
```

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me improve the server so it can serve multiple clients' message at the same time.

Comment: If your response handling blocks or takes a long time, then a good way would be to read in the response in your `receive_info()` and then launch a thread that does the actual processing. Execution of this thread would take as long as it takes but it would not block your main loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to run  your code and test, but if your problem is `receive_info()` blocking, you would bypass that by launching a thread to handle the actual response. Something like this (might contain typos, I wasn't able to test with your code - for example no idea what `flow` is.)

```
def handle_response(self, data):
    logging.info("[received_data] data <{}>".format(flow))
    self.rep_socket.send(b"\x00")
    self.blocking_op(data)

def received_info(self):
        while True:
            # logging.debug("[received_flow] ")
            cl_data = self.rep_socket.recv_json()
            _t = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_response, args=(cl_data,))
            _t.start()
```

This has your `received_info()` loop as it is, but instead of doing the processing there, a new thread is launched to process the response. It takes what it takes to complete and then the thread dies, but your `received_info()` will be immediately ready to wait for new responses.

Comment: Thank you very much Hannu, it worked. by the way in  args=(cl_data,) why there is a coma after cl_data?


one extra question: Do you think if I want to handle say 1000 clients is it better to use Threads or to use gevent ( or asyncio)?

Comment: The comma is there as you are only passing one argument and `args` must be a tuple. If you passed several arguments, you could state args=(a,b,c) without the trailing comma, but it is the simplest way to create a tuple out of one item.

Comment: I am not an expert on asyncio, so can't comment on performance. Python is not the most efficient parallel processing language anyway because of GIL. Try threads and if there is a problem, investigate it. You might be absolutely fine with threads.